# Dealing with whitespace when parsing XML

Tags: cocoa-touch, whitespace, xml-parsing

I have problem with parsing XML.

I parsed data of cities, Amsterdam & Den Bosch.

Amsterdam works fine but Den Bosch does not.

No doubt it is due to space problem. 
Den Bosch has a white space.

Should I trim the whitespace in my application or the web service?

Which would be the best to handle the space problem?

EDIT:
The OP and @PeterMurray-Rust seem to agree that the problem is that the third-party app returns URL-escaped strings of the form:

```
"Den%20Bosch"
```

%20 is not recognized by XML as anything special and that it will be necessary to replace occurrences by spaces. A typical scripting approach would be

```
s/%20/ /g
```

This is likely to be quite a common problem although I'm not clear why content should be URL-encoded.

[OP please comment if I have got this wrong]

Comment: for space i need to replace %20.... what is the best way to do?

Comment: You will need to show a small amount of data for us to work out what your problem is. Strings are treated differently in attribute values and in element content. You say it doesn't "work" - what is it that is not what you want?

Comment: @Jon Winstanley thanks for editing... i am sorry about my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your update I assume that the data is something like:

```
<city>Den%20Bosch</city>
```

The string "%20" is three characters which XML does not regard as having any specific meaning. Depending on your language or whether you use XSLT you will need to replace them. In Java and the XOM library I might write

```
String value = cityNode.getValue().replaceAll("%20", " ");
```

I can't help with the specifics of Cocoa - I think you'll have to investigate the API to find how to get content values.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust...Thanks a lot ... And understand too :)

Answer (score 1):

I Assume that you are parsing xml at application level and also by white space you mean the trailing white spaces and not the one in between the words "Den" and "Bosch". In anycase, I think you can trim the spaces at web service level, since you can be rest assured that any call coming from any other application using this web service need not have to trim the spaces since web service handles that internally. This would be a one-point change for you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about cocoa and your xml as well. City names, are these inner text of node or tag name. If it is in tag name or attributes without quotes, it will fail. If it is in inner text, it should work. However, there is CDATA fragment which tells the parser to ignore the contents

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the code i implemented its working fine..........


if ([appDelegate.cityListArray count]>0) {
        aDJInfo=[appDelegate.cityListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//http://compliantbox.com/party_temperature/citysearch.php?city=Amsterdam&latitude=52.366125&longitude=4.899171
        url=@"http://compliantbox.com/party_temperature/citysearch.php?city=";
        NSString *string=[aDJInfo.city_Name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
        url=[url stringByAppendingString:string];
        NSLog(@"abbbbbbbbbbb %@",string);
        url=[url stringByAppendingString:@"&latitude=52.366125&longitude=4.899171"];
        [self parseEventName:[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:url]];
    }
}
```

@All thanks a lot..